# Retrofit 2.0 для Андроид

Tags: java, android, retrofit

Интересуюсь библиоткеой `Retrofit 2.0` Прочитал уйму коментов как положительных так же и отрицательныö .как я понел он позволяет экономить размер кода Http запроса и Json ответ !)
1)Хотелось бы узнать ваше  мнение о нем об его альтернативах

2)Плюсы минусы

3)хороший туториал по нему я не нашел нормального

4)Если есть экземпляр с коментами

Спасибо

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Основной ее плюс заключается в том (собственно, как и плюс любой другой библиотеки), что для получения желаемого результата, Вы можете пользоваться уже готовыми методами (из этой библиотеки), нежели писать свои.

Как правило, работоспособность библиотеки проверена многими разработчиками, следовательно, она будет работать стабильнее (не в общем случае, конечно, но в большинстве), чем самописные методы.

Резюмирую, скажу – это просто удобно. Многие из тех задач, которые Вы будете решать, уже решены за Вас. Вам лишь остается пользоваться готовыми результатами.

Плюсы (они же возможности), на вскидку:

1. Автоматическое преобразование JSON в объекты;
2. Нет необходимости выделять запросы в отдельный поток – они уже и так там выполняются;
3. Динамическое построение запросов;
4. Обработка ошибок.

Почитать подробнее, можно, например, [здесь](http://java-help.ru/retrofit-2-review/) или [здесь](http://square.github.io/retrofit/).

Но я твердо уверен, что перед использованием библиотек, *в учебных целях*, просто необходимо поизобретать собственный велосипед, чтобы иметь примерное представление того, как это все работает изнутри.

Comment: Спасибо за отет и материал